# Sound is not working for UINotification

Tags: ios, ipad

I have done with my `UINotification` in my iPad App. I am trying to add sound to my notification message. I tried both default and custom one which I have added in my bundle but both are not working.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];

UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
localNotification.fireDate = nil;
localNotification.alertBody = @"Message";
localNotification.soundName = @"ALERT.mp3";  // UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] presentLocalNotificationNow:localNotification];
```

both are not working, I could not hear any thing.

Comment: Can you show me your method?

Comment: hey try to fix fire date and close the app then you check that you notificatication and sound is comming or not

Answer (score 0):

Try this
and check if your sound file should not be bigger than 30
 seconds.
write this in your app delegate

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];


- (void)scheduleNotification {
    Class cls = NSClassFromString(@"UILocalNotification");
    if (cls != nil) {
            UILocalNotification *notif = [[cls alloc] init]; 
            notif.fireDate = insert your date;
            notif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
            notif.alertBody = your message body;
            notif.repeatInterval = 0;
            notif.soundName =  UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notif];
            [notif release];
    }
}
```

Comment: Apple Doc say [Sounds that last longer than 30 seconds are not supported](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UILocalNotification/soundName). Where did you get or find 26 seconds?

Comment: @BlackFrog yes bro, its 30 sec

Comment: i tried ur code … but not working.. i mean could not hear anything… is there any setting i need to do … ALERT.mp3 is small file doc. saying is sound is longer then default one will be assigned but i can not hear any thing..

Comment: i tried all possible way, even i check notification setting for my APP , sound is ON, is there anything else i need to look…device volume full

Comment: you may add fire date after receiving web response, there is nothing complicated to do like this.

Comment: yes my app received all notification. once it run when ever user change some thing other end my App get notification, both pop up and added to notification centre… but no sound :(

Comment: can you upload didReceiveLocalNotification method ?

Comment: I am yet to find solution      - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
{
    /*UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"MYApp" message:notification.alertBody delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alertView show];*/

 }

Comment: i have sound Alert.aiff less then 30 sec, but i can not hear even default one.

Comment: code is working fine in my device for both default and custom sound.It may be ur device setting problem.